# C# equivalent for PHP file_put_contents

Tags: c#, php

I am converting a PHP file to C#,completed 75%,stuck with these lines

```
if(file_put_contents($uploaddir.$randomName, $decodedData)) {
    //echo $randomName.":uploaded successfully"; //NO NEED TO CONVERT ECHO PART
}
```

PHP Brothers please help

**MORE INFO**

I converted ***this***

```
// Encode it correctly
$encodedData = str_replace(' ','+',$data[1]);
$decodedData = base64_decode($encodedData);
```

***to this***

```
// Encode it correctly
string encodedData = data[1].Replace(' ', '+');
string decodedData = base64Decode(encodedData);
```

where base64Decode ***is***

```
public static string base64Decode(string data)
{
    byte[] binary = Convert.FromBase64String(data);
    return Encoding.Default.GetString(binary);
}
```

Comment: [file_put_contents()](http://php.net/file_put_contents) writes a string to a file, so you need to open a file, write the string to it and then close the file.. how to actually code this in c# is beyond me but that's the gist of the flow.

Comment: @shadyyx - if you just answered the question instead of complaining, everyone else who googles for `C# write content to a file` would get the answer *here*.

Comment: @hajikelist Pardon me? Where the heck did you come to my nickname here? I have nothing to do with any content here within the question, it's comments, answers nor their comments...

Comment: I flagged your comment that's why. it's been removed, I'm sure if you check your comment history in your profile you'll see the comment I'm referring to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText (uploaddir + randomname, decodedData);
```

See the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext.aspx) for details on the `WriteAllText` method.

However, your approach of converting your data to a byte array, and then converting it to a string in the `base64Decode` method, followed by writing it to the file is a bit too complicated IMO. You can just write your byte array to a file, decode the data like this:

```
public static byte[] base64Decode(string data)
{
    return Convert.FromBase64String(data);
}
```

and then call

```
byte[] decodedData = base64Decode(encodedData);
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(uploaddir + randomname, decodedData);
```

WriteAllBytes documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes.aspx).

Comment: this did great,also your advice regarding encoding made my day.

Answer (score 2):

Closest analogon is probably [System.IO.File.WriteAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143376.aspx)

```
string uploaddir;
string randomName;
string decodedData;
// ....
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(
  System.IO.Path.Combine(uploaddir, randomName),
  decodedData
);
```